# How to properly update state in this Redux reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have an action that returns a payload containing a filtered object. I want this object to be returned as the new state or the piece of state that I am to show the user.

The specific case I am talking about show up in the following code under:

```
case Paginate_BLOG
   return {...state, action.payload.data};
```

The full code of my blog reducer:

```
import { FETCH_POSTS, FETCH_POST, DELETE_POST, PAGINATE_BLOG} from '../actions';
import _ from 'lodash';

export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_POST:
      const post = action.payload.data;
      return { ...state, [post.id]: post};
    case FETCH_POSTS:
      return _.mapKeys(action.payload.data, 'id');
    case PAGINATE_BLOG:
      return {...state, action.payload.data};
    case DELETE_POST:
      return _.omit(state, action.payload);
    default:
      return state;
   }
}
```

So basically I am trying to implement pagination in a blog using redux to update the state as a subset of the original set of blogs that I fetched into state.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you mean `{...state, data: action.payload.data}`

I didn't even think that was valid - but if it is, then I think you're returning a new state with a key `action.payload.data` with the value of `action.payload.data`

```
{
  ...,
  data: // previous data,
  "action.payload.data": ...action.payload.data 
}
```